# Issue with table captions

Tags: tables, captions

I have been writing my thesis in LaTeX and has always managed to fix any issues that arose but I just can't go anywhere with this one... :s.

Basically any table that I have in my document has the same issue. Their cpation is messed up, it says "Table X:" then inserts a line break before inserting the caption... I could not find in my style sheet.

Here is a typical example, both the code and the result as a picture...

```
\begin{table}[!h]\small \centering{}
  \begin{tabulary}{1\textwidth}{C C C C C}
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$\gamma$-criterion}\\
    & {1 mm / 0.5 \%} & {1 mm / 1 \%} & {2 mm / 0.5 \%} & {2 mm / 0.1 \%}\\
    \hline \hline
    Field & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Passing rate \%}\\
    \hline
    Spine sarcoma & 93.7 & 92.9 & 94.9 & 96.9\\
    Pericardia and lung sarcoma & 93.6 & 92.7 & 95.2 & 97.3\\
    Head \& neck field 1 & 94.4 & 93.3 & 95.1 & 97.0\\ 
    Head \& neck field 2 & 94.0 & 92.9 & 94.2 & 96.7\\ 
  \end{tabulary}
  \caption{3D $\gamma$-analyses results between GMC's water dose recomputation and the original QA dose computations. Numerous gamma criteria were used.}
  \label{GMCtab2}
\end{table}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Please help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This most likely has to do with your choice of document class and packages. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If I add some minimal instructions to make your sample code compilable, I do *not* get a line break between the float's number and the colon. This strongly suggests that somewhere in either your preamble or in one of the captions you load, there's an instruction that either inserts the unwanted line break directly or loads a package (such as `caption`) that provides an easy interface for inserting such a line break. Summing up: Please augment your code snippet into a compilable MWE that generates the problem behavior you're looking to avoid.

Comment: By the way `\centering` does not take an argument so the `{}` is useless.

Comment: In case you find the answer useful, you should consider [accepting it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1853/15874).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would typeset the table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  margin = 3cm % avoids `overfull \hbox' warning
]{geometry}
\usepackage[
  tableposition = top, % correct spacing between table and caption
  width = 0.76\textwidth % relative width of the caption
]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs} % horizontal lines in table
\usepackage{siunitx} % SI units


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \centering
 \small
  \caption{3D $\gamma$-analyses results between GMC's water dose recomputation and
           the original QA dose computations. Numerous gamma criteria were used.}
  \label{GMCtable2}
  \begin{tabular}{l *{4}{S[table-format = 2.1]}}
    \toprule
      & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$\gamma$-criterion}\\[1ex]
      & \SI{1}{\mm}/\SI{0.5}{\percent}
      & \SI{1}{\mm}/\SI{1}{\percent}
      & \SI{2}{\mm}/\SI{0.5}{\percent}
      & \SI{1}{\mm}/\SI{0.1}{\percent}\\
    \midrule
        Field
      & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Passing rate (\si{\percent})}\\[1ex]
    Spine sarcoma               & 93.7 & 92.9 & 94.9 & 96.9\\
    Pericardia and lung sarcoma & 93.6 & 92.7 & 95.2 & 97.3\\
    Head \& neck field~1        & 94.4 & 93.3 & 95.1 & 97.0\\
    Head \& neck field~2        & 94.0 & 92.9 & 94.2 & 96.7\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
This is table~\ref{GMCtable2}.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]